Multiply the value determined for each section
I am in a situation where I need to multiply several columns by the value corresponding to the interval.
I'm using Pandas, but I'm using a for loop to get the value as follows.
I think there is a better way than this, can someone give me some advice?
sample:
import pandas as pd

d = {
    5: 5,
    4: 7,
    3: 2,
    2: -4,
    1: -5,
}
def mul(value):
    if value < 1: return value * 0.01
    elif 5 < value: return value * 20
    for k, v in d.items():
        if value <= k:
            val = value * v
            break
    return val

a = [
    {'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 2},
    {'a': 4, 'b': 0.5, 'c': 4},
    {'a': 3.5, 'b': 1.5, 'c': 5},
    {'a': 2.1, 'b': 5, 'c': 6},
    {'a': 0.1, 'b': 1, 'c': 7},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
a = []
b = []
for i in df.values:
    a.append(mul(i[0]))
    b.append(mul(i[1]))
df['a1'] = a
df['b1'] = b
print(df.head())

"""
     a     b     c      a1       b1
0  5.0  10.0   2.0  25.000  200.000
1  4.0   0.5   4.0  20.000    0.005
2  3.5   1.5   5.0  17.500    7.500
3  2.1   5.0   6.0  10.500   25.000
4  0.1   1.0   7.0   0.001    5.000
"""


Your updated question is quite different from the original one. The logic is not the same, the output will depend on the order of the keys in the dictionary.

i get it. Then I guess I'll have to create a new question. @mozway

Updated answer to the edited question
Since the question was edited, the logic changed a lot and you can't easily vectorize your operation. Mapping of the values strongly depends on the internal logic of the mul function and here is dependent on the order of the keys in the dictionary.
Without vectorizing, you could simplify your code to:
cols = ['a', 'b']
out = df.join(df[cols].map(mul).add_suffix('1'))

Output:
     a     b  c      a1       b1
0  5.0  10.0  2  25.000  200.000
1  4.0   0.5  4  20.000    0.005
2  3.5   1.5  5  17.500    7.500
3  2.1   5.0  6  10.500   25.000
4  0.1   1.0  7   0.001    5.000

Original answer to the initial question
This is exactly what numpy.searchsorted is doing, just combine it with integer array indexing:
import numpy as np

k = np.array(list(d))          # array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
v = np.array(list(d.values())) # array([-5, -4,  2,  7,  5])

out = df.mul(v[np.searchsorted(k, df)])

NB. the keys in d must be sorted. Also, this uses the default side='left' parameter of searchsorted.
Output:
      a     b
0  25.0  -8.0
1  28.0  -2.5
2  24.5  -6.0
3   4.2  25.0
4  -5.0  -5.0

To combine to the original DataFrame, join:
out = df.join(df.mul(v[np.searchsorted(k, df)]).add_suffix('1'))

Output:
     a    b    a1    b1
0  5.0  2.0  25.0  -8.0
1  4.0  0.5  28.0  -2.5
2  3.5  1.5  24.5  -6.0
3  2.1  5.0   4.2  25.0
4  1.0  1.0  -5.0  -5.0

Intermediate (indices of matching values in k):
# np.searchsorted(k, df)
array([[4, 1],
       [3, 0],
       [3, 1],
       [2, 4],
       [0, 0]])


Compared to Pandas' cut, is this method faster?

@django.seolpyo.com yes it should be. It is vectorized to work on all values at once. No need to loop over columns, like with cut

Can you check Changed the mul function? Also, how do I work by specifying only columns a and b of df?

I got an error ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (45, 21): given (45, 4)

If you want to limit to specific columns: cols = ['a', 'b'] ; out = df.join(df[cols].mul(v[np.searchsorted(k, df[cols])]).add_suffix('1')).

Code
use cut
bins = [float('-inf')] + list(d.keys())

out = pd.concat([
    df,
    df.apply(lambda x: pd.cut(x, bins=bins, labels=d.values()))
      .astype('float')
      .mul(df)
      .add_suffix('1')
], axis=1)

out:
     a    b    a1    b1
0  5.0  2.0  25.0  -8.0
1  4.0  0.5  28.0  -2.5
2  3.5  1.5  24.5  -6.0
3  2.1  5.0   4.2  25.0
4  1.0  1.0  -5.0  -5.0


Can you tell me why you are adding float('-inf')?

@django.seolpyo.com chk linked document of cut and read about bins and labels
